# VBA RegEx pattern issue

Tags: regex, vba

I have the following RegEx, which works in the RegEx online tester:
https://regex101.com/r/sZkhfs/1

What I want to do is get the whole text String between "Freigaben: " and any text string followed by a ":" (colon).

**Pattern**
"`(?<=Freigaben: )([\S\s]*?)(?=\s[a-zA-Z]++:)`"

**Test String**
"Freigaben: BLA BLABLABLABLABLABLBAL test ...
Empfehlungen:"

When I try to run it in my VBA code I face an 5018/5017 error, which means the pattern is wrong, but I do not figured it out how to change it accordingly so that it will run in my VBA Code.
Any ideas?

Comment: `Freigaben:\s*([\S\s]*?)(?=\s+[a-zA-Z]+:|$)` and grab the `Submatches(0)`.

Comment: wow, yes that worked thanks! I had to collect submatches number 3, but I guess it's related to the array collection.

Comment: still have to figure out what the differences mean in the pattern to VBA. I could see that "lookbehind" is not possible in VBA, but isn't it a lookbehind somehow?

Comment: If you mean `(?=...)`, it is a lookahead, not a lookbehind. The VBA regex package is built on ECMAScript 5 specs and it supports a lot of things, but not lookbehinds and not possessive quantifiers like `++`.